# Issues with jQuery .on( 'click' ) API call

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, api

I have been working on a simple weather app project. The user enters a zip code into an input element which (upon clicking a button element) makes an API call to wunderground.com. A few pieces of data are then grabbed from the JSON object, stringified and inserted into the DOM.

```
(function() {
        var wundergroundAPI = "https://api.wunderground.com/api/3b411ca908826af8/conditions/q/";
        var input = $('input');

        $('#submit').on('click', function() {
            var inputValue = input.val();
            var weatherByZip = wundergroundAPI += inputValue += '.json';
            $.getJSON(weatherByZip, function(json) {
                $('#temp-f')
                .text('Temperature: ' + JSON.stringify(json['current_observation']['temp_f']) + ' F');
                $('#location')
                .text('Location: '+ JSON.stringify(json['current_observation']['display_location']['full']));
                $('#weather')
                .text('Weather: ' + JSON.stringify(json['current_observation']['weather']));
                input.val("");
            })
        });
    })();
```

The jQuery works fine on the first API call.

```
GET https://api.wunderground.com/api/3b411ca908826af8/conditions/q/70118.json
```

However, the second API call does not.

```
GET https://api.wunderground.com/api/3b411ca908826af8/conditions/q/70118.json06840.json
```

The issue seems to be in the way I declare the weatherByZip variable:

```
var weatherByZip = wundergroundAPI += inputValue += '.json';
```

What I intended was that the weatherByZip variable would be updated (with a new inputValue plus the .json extension) each time the function is called. What happens instead is that the inputValue and .json are appended to the end of the previously created variable.

```
70118.json06840.json
70118.json06840.json90210.json
```

How would I fix my jQuery function so as to rectify this problem. That is, each time the function is called (a button element is clicked) a new/updated API call occurs?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Change += to +

```
var weatherByZip = wundergroundAPI + inputValue + '.json';
```

wundergroundAPI += inputValue means: take the existing value of wundergroundAPI and concatenate the value of inputValue behind that. That's the reason your wundergroundAPI keeps getting longer.

Comment: Thank you Alain Stoffels! It worked perfectly. Sometimes I get so wrapped up in a problem that I can overlook simple solutions. I kept thinking of what jQuery method to use rather than changing my operators.

Answer (score 2):

```
 var inputValue = input.val();
 var weatherByZip = wundergroundAPI + inputValue + '.json';
```

Even more safe would be to trim `inputValue`, to remove blank spaces if the user adds them.

```
 var inputValue = input.val().trim();
```

Know that, however, it isn't supported in IE8. You need a polyfill for that.

**Edit**: As @Kevin B mentioned, *jQuery* offers a trim method that works on all platforms. If you need to support IE8- or don't want to copy/paste a polyfill, use it, like this:

```
var inputValue = $.trim(input.val());
```

Comment: *Know that, however, it isn't supported in IE8.* fortunately jquery has a method for that too.

Comment: Didn't know that, thanks. Do you know if the method works on IE 8- ?

Comment: Yes, since that's why they added it. http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.trim/

Comment: great, makes sense. On my part, I'd still not use it because I don't support IE8-. But still wanted to make sure the OP knew it

Comment: I appreciate the insight jonathanGB. I did set the maxlength attribute on my input element to 5. Would that make blank spaces a non-issue since the input is for US zip codes?

Comment: I think it's always a good measure on text inputs. E.g. what happens if someone puts "abcd "?